# OutofMemoryException while using Wicket DataTable

Tags: mysql, wicket, out-of-memory

I have a simple wicket application which displays 4-5 data table in a page.The data provider is quite huge here.It has probably millions of data in it.I am displaying these data using data table.
The query to display the data is a simple "select * from..".I am using MySQL Database

I do not face the outofMemoryExcpetion,while displaying relatively small data ,but the out of memory Exception occurs when there is huge data in DB.

Tried using Loadable-Detachable model,which did not pay any way to resolve the issue.

The page takes around 10 mins to load, but ultimately I get a out of memory exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use paging... Use `DataTable` with `IDataProvider`.
In DataProvider you need to retreive not all table but a part of it.
An example [here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/repeater/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.repeater.PagingPage?0).

Comment: Thanks..Will try it.But just wondering,is there any known problems/issue with Datatables, when the DB size is huge?

Comment: Are you talking about wicket component org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.DataTable?

Comment: Yes the same one..I am trying to figure out how different a DataTable is from DataView (Performance wise)

Comment: You can use DataTable instead of DataView. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Have you implemented IDataProvider or just used some existing implementation like ListDataProvider?

Comment: I am currently using DataTable with IDataProvider implementation .I am using ScrollableDataprovider.This gives me out of memory exception.

Comment: Can't find ScrollableDataprovider... try to implement IDataProvider and use it with DataTable.

Comment: My bad,it is SortableDataProvider. It already has a default implementation of IDataProvider

Comment: Show how you are using SortableDataProvider with DataTable please.